# Exception encountered when calling layer 'lstm' (type LSTM)

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, lstm

I am trying to build a time series model using LSTM to predict money printing values. Dataset contains monthly money printing records, so have used the sequence_order as 12. Following is the code segment whener the issue lies.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define the LSTM model
model = Sequential()

# Add an LSTM layer with 50 units (you can adjust this as needed)
model.add(LSTM(50, activation='relu', input_shape=(sequence_length, 1)))

# Add a dense output layer
model.add(Dense(1))

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

# Train the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=50, batch_size=32, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))


# Make predictions on the training and testing data
y_train_pred = model.predict(X_train)
y_test_pred = model.predict(X_test)

#Let us check the mean squared error
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from math import sqrt
y_test.mean()
rmse=sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test_pred,y_test))
print('root mean squared error of testing data:',rmse)

# Inverse transform the scaled predictions to the original scale
y_train_pred = scaler.inverse_transform(y_train_pred)
y_test_pred = scaler.inverse_transform(y_test_pred)
y_train_actual = scaler.inverse_transform(y_train.reshape(-1, 1))
y_test_actual = scaler.inverse_transform(y_test.reshape(-1, 1))

# Use the 'Month' data as the time index
time_index_train = df['Month'].iloc[:len(y_train+1)]
time_index_test = df['Month'].iloc[len(y_train):len(y_train)+len(y_test)]

# Plot the training data, testing data, predicted values, and actual values
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.plot(time_index_train, y_train_actual, label='Training Actual', color='blue')
plt.plot(time_index_train, y_train_pred, label='Training Predicted', linestyle='dashed', color='green')
plt.plot(time_index_test, y_test_actual, label='Testing Actual', color='red')
plt.plot(time_index_test, y_test_pred, label='Testing Predicted', linestyle='dashed', color='orange')

plt.title('LSTM Model Predictions vs. Actual')
plt.xlabel('Month')
plt.ylabel('Money_Printing Value')
plt.legend()
plt.xticks(rotation=45)  # Rotate x-axis labels for readability
plt.tight_layout()  # Ensure labels fit within the plot area
plt.show()



#Lets try to predict future values
start_date = '2023-01-01'
end_date = '2027-12-01'

# Generate monthly date range for 2023-2027
future_date_range = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='M')

# Use the last 'sequence_length' data points from the original data to start prediction
input_sequence = df['Money_Printing'].values[-sequence_length:].reshape(1, -1, 1)
print(input_sequence.shape)
print(type(input_sequence))

# Initialize a list to store predicted values
predicted_values = []

# Define the number of steps to predict (number of months in the future)
num_steps = len(future_date_range)

# Loop to predict each step
for _ in range(num_steps):
    print(input_sequence.shape)
    print(type(input_sequence))
    # Predict the next value
    **prediction = model.predict(input_sequence)**
    
    # Append the prediction to the list
    predicted_values.append(prediction[0][0])
    
    # Update the input sequence for the next prediction
    input_sequence = np.roll(input_sequence, shift=-1, axis=1)  # Shift values left
    input_sequence[0, -1, 0] = prediction[0][0]  # Set the last value to the prediction


# Create a DataFrame to store the predicted values with dates
predicted_df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': future_date_range, 'Predicted_Money_Printing': predicted_values})

# Set 'Date' as the index
predicted_df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)


# Plot the predicted 'Money_Printing' values
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.plot(predicted_df.index, predicted_df['Predicted_Money_Printing'], label='Predicted Money_Printing', color='blue')

plt.title('Predicted Money_Printing Values (2023-2027)')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Money_Printing Value')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Highlighted code segment gives me the follwing error.

```
TypeError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'lstm' (type LSTM).

'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Call arguments received by layer 'lstm' (type LSTM):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=<unknown>, dtype=float32)
  • mask=None
  • training=False
  • initial_state=None
```

Can anyone please help me to sort this out.

I am trying to predict the money printing values for following years (starting from 2023).

```
# Loop to predict each step
for _ in range(num_steps):
    print(input_sequence.shape)
    print(type(input_sequence))
    # Predict the next value
    prediction = model.predict(input_sequence)
    
    # Append the prediction to the list
    predicted_values.append(prediction[0][0])
    
    # Update the input sequence for the next prediction
    input_sequence = np.roll(input_sequence, shift=-1, axis=1)  # Shift values left
    input_sequence[0, -1, 0] = prediction[0][0]  # Set the last value to the prediction
```

when I try to get those predictions using the LSTM model, it seems like there is an issue with the input_sequence variable.

Comment: How do you define the  model`? Do you train/fit it? Please post a fully working code.

Comment: I just updated the code with the model development codes.